# CakePHP Session Timeout Not as Programmed?

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cookies, session-cookies

I'm experiencing session timeouts in CakePHP quicker than I code. I have this line:

```
'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'timeout'=>24*60*60*30//for one month
],
```

....But it is logging out around 30 minutes of inactivity I believe, at least it feels around there.

Any idea how to fix this or investigate where the problem is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Check your session cookies expiration date, it may expire before the session on the server actually times out. Also make sure that `ini_set()` is allowed, as CakePHP needs to modify the `session.gc_maxlifetime` value, it is being read back and used to determine the inactivity timeout. ps, please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt` or `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'php',
        'timeout' => 24*60*60*30, // The session will timeout after 30 minutes of inactivity
        'cookieTimeout' => 1440, // The session cookie will live for at most 24 hours, this does not effect session timeouts
        'checkAgent' => false,
        'autoRegenerate' => true, // causes the session expiration time to reset on each page load
],
```

Answer (score 0):

`php` is not the most robust default:

> ```
> The built in defaults are:
>
> - 'php' - Uses settings defined in your php.ini.
> - 'cake' - Saves session files in CakePHP's /tmp directory.
> - 'database' - Uses CakePHP's database sessions.
> - 'cache' - Use the Cache class to save sessions.
> ```

I'd use `cake` instead, so you can have your own session directory. That way, other apps with shorter expiration time will not remove *your* session files.

Answer (score 0):

```
'Session' => [
'cookie'=>'webapp',
'timeout' => 4320,
'cookieTimeout'=> 4320
],
```